# structures and pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
     using namespace std;


     struct demo{
       int one;
       int two;
       int three;
     };
    int main()
    {
       demo d1;
             demo *dptr=&d1;

            *dptr=1 ;  
            ++dptr;
            *dptr=2;
            ++dptr;
            *dptr=3;

        return 0;
    }
```

Please explain why the above code looks logical but in fact does not work
in line 13 of code. Log error:

> no match for '`operator=`' in '`*dptr=1`'

Comment: Because you're effectively doing `d1 = 1;` - how would that work?

Comment: You're trying to set the value of a demo struct to an int, what?

Comment: thanks immibis, silly me

Comment: The code doesn't look logical to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 demo d1;
 demo *dptr=&d1;

 *dptr=1 ;  
 ++dptr;
 dptr=2;
 ++dptr;
 dptr=3;
```

`dptr` is a pointer pointing to a `demo` struct. So, `*dptr = 1` is basically the same as `d1 = 1;`, that's not valid.

Plus, having a pointer of that type and doing `++` on that pointer applies pointer arithmetic for that type, shoving the pointer `sizeof(demo)`, that's not what you want here. You'll need to create an `int` pointer by casting it, then using that pointer to read the 3 fields

```
int* dptr=reinterpret_cast<int*>(&d1);
```

Padding can still ruin your day though, however, since they're all `int`'s you should be fine.

Comment: well understood Gill, but i suppose if I take this option [int* dptr=reinterpret_cast<int*>(&d1);]   someone would ask, ''why not just use an array then if all members are int type?" right?

Comment: @user3568438 Perhaps yeah, I'm not sure what your use case is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your `dptr` as `int*`, not `demo*`.

```
int *dptr=&d1; // might need type cast (int*)

*dptr=1 ;
```